# how to get checkbox list to be checked depending on the db values in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, checkbox

I have got a checboxlist in edit products page, I want the checkbox list to be 
checked depending on the db values.

For instance I am saving the values in db as 1,2,3
Therfore the checkboxlist with the value 1 , value 2 , value 3 should be checked.

Below is the code:
Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        ITrackdayRepository trackdayResp = new TrackdayRepository();
        IQueryable<Object> getAllproducts = trackdayResp.GetProductsSelectlist();

        ViewData["products"] = new SelectList(getAllproducts.ToList(), "productID", "Name");//all events for checkboxlist
        IVoucherRepository voucherResp = new VoucherRepository();
        Voucher voucher = voucherResp.GetVoucher(id);
        return View(voucher);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Admin/Voucher/Edit/5

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection)
    {
        try
        {
            // TODO: update the selected checkbox nd do db insert

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

View:

```
 <tr>
        <td>
        <label>Products</label>
        </td>
        <td>
         <% foreach (var item in (SelectList)ViewData["products"]) { %>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="Name" value="<%=item.Value %>" />
                  <label for="<%=item.Value%>"><%=item.Text%></label>
                  <br />

        <% } %>  
        </td>
        </tr>
```

edited:

```
 <td>
         <% foreach (var item in (SelectList)ViewData["events"]) { %>


                     <%var test = ViewData["arrays"];  %>
                    <%string checkString = test.ToString().Contains(item.Value) ? "checked=\"checked\"":string.Empty; %>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="Name" value="<%=item.Value %>" checked="<%=checkString %>" />
                  <label for="<%=item.Value%>"><%=item.Text%></label>
                  <br />

        <% } %>  
        </td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a checkbox to be checked you need to set the checked attribute on the input element

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Name" value="<%=item.Value %>" checked="checked" />
```

EDIT:

Assuming you always want 1, 2, or 3 checked you can do this:

```
  <% var valuesToCheck = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };

    foreach (var item in (SelectList)ViewData["products"]) { 
       string checkedString = valuesToCheck.Contains(item.productID) ? "checked=/"checked/" : string.empty;
    %>
     <input type="checkbox" name="Name" value="<%=item.Value %>" <%=checkedString%> />
     <label for="<%=item.Value%>"><%=item.Text%></label>
     <br />

<% } %>
```

I would probably pass over the values you want checked as part of your viewmodel or if you aren't using one in ViewData so as to not define a list in the view.

Comment: I know that but i dont want to check all the checkboxes just the checkbox which has values matching db values

Comment: @Mr A - which object/property contains the db values and which contains all the other values?

Comment: item.productID contains values like 1,2,3 therfore I want the checked box to be checked whose value is 1 nd 2 nd 3

Comment: @Mr A - So you always want 1,2,3 to be checked? If item.productID can be other values, how do you know which values you want to check?

Comment: no that was just an example , the values can change item.productId can have 5,4,6 etc these are the ids which are saved in the db , What I ma thinking to separate these values from comma and save in the array and then somehow passed to checkbox to be checked , is this possible

Comment: how can one write  string like  string checkedString in the view

Comment: I tried the above edited code with no success , now all the check boxes are checked , i have added the code in my question

Comment: with my code i m getting input type="checkbox" name="Name" value="91" checked="" />
 in the source code

Comment: Error:The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>.Contains(int)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @Mr A - You're getting that error since you are using a string and not a list of ints when using `Contains`.